# Reverse sublist while chaining and grouping list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
nodes = [
    ["630505499", "630507607"], 
    ["630507607", "633597294"], 
    ["630512154", "633597294"],  # needs to be flipped before grouping
    ["630512154", "630512151"]
]
```

And want this result:

```
["630505499", "630507607", "633597294", "630512154", "630512151"]
```

Right now, I only have something that works when nothing needs to be flipped:

```
[x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(itertools.chain(*nodes))]
```

Comment: Yes, I want to remove duplicates. That is why I am using groupby. Every sublist's last element either equals the subsequent sublist's first element or the subsequent sublist needs to be flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and chain, the OrderedDict will remove dupes while preserving the order:

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(itertools.chain(*nodes)).keys()))

['630505499', '630507607', '633597294', '630512154', '630512151']
```

I don't see how groupby could really fit into what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to flatten the lists and keep only the unique values, something like -

```
>>> nodes = [
...     ["630505499", "630507607"],
...     ["630507607", "633597294"],
...     ["630512154", "633597294"],  # needs to be flipped before grouping
...     ["630512154", "630512151"]
... ]
>>> newnodes = []
>>> for i in (y for x in nodes for y in x):
...     if i not in newnodes:
...             newnodes.append(i)
>>> newnodes
['630505499', '630507607', '633597294', '630512154', '630512151']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to flip the list when element in tail & head are not matched, here is an example code with [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) mentioned by [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham).

```
from collections import OrderedDict                                                                           

 nodes = [                                                                      
     ["630505499", "630507607"],                                                
     ["630507607", "633597294"],                                                
     ["630512154", "633597294"],  # needs to be flipped before grouping         
     ["630512154", "630512151"]                                                 
]                                                                              

def f(x, y):                                                                   
     return x + (y if x[-1] == y[0] else y[::-1])                               

print list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(reduce(f, nodes)).keys())
```